# lodash / js: Filtering values within an object based on regular expressions and getting the highest by comparison

Tags: javascript, lodash

For the following json

```
[
  {       
    "index": "xyz",
    ...
  },
  {       
    "index": "abc1234",
    ...
  },
  {       
    "index": "xyz",
    ...
  },
  {       
    "index": "abc5678",
    ...
  }
 ...
```

I want to filter out abc values and `xyz` values separately.

I tried the following to get values

```
  var x = _.filter(jsonData, function (o) { 
      return /abc/i.test(o.index); 
  });
```

and it worked to give the filtered outputs.

Now i want to get the highest of `abc` values that is if there values `abc123`, `abc444`, `abc999` then the code should return `abc999`.

I can loop over again using lodash but could this be done in a single call - within the same one that filters out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\D+/` to match and remove characters that are not digits. Check if previous number portion of string is less than current number portion of string

```js
var jsonData = [
  {       
    "index": "xyz",
  },
  {       
    "index": "abc1234",
  },
  {       
    "index": "xyz",
  },
  {       
    "index": "abc5678",
  },
  {       
    "index": "abc1",
  }];

  var x = jsonData.reduce(function (o, prop) { 
           return /abc/i.test(prop.index) 
                  ? !o || +prop.index.replace(/\D+/, "") > +o.replace(/\D+/, "")
                    ? prop.index
                    : o
                  : o
          }, 0);
  
  console.log(x);
```

Comment: var largestIndex = jsonData.reduce(function (o, prop) {
    numIndx++;
    if (/abc/i.test(prop.index)) {        
        return !o || prop.index.replace(/\D+/, "") > o.replace(/\D+/, "")? prop.index : o;
    }
    return o;
},0);

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 - I have modified your version as above to make it bit clearer (lest I would've got it reviewed out). Kindly take a look at let me know if there is any issue with this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the highest `abc{SOME_NUMBER}` value and filter at the same time, you can just use regular iteration instead of `_.filter`:

```js
let jsonData = [{"index": "xyz"},{"index": "abc1234"}, {"index": "xyz"},{"index": "abc5678"}];

let max = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // value for the max number at the end of "abc"
let item;                          // item containing the max abc${NUMBER} value
let filtered = [];                 // filtered array containing abc strings

jsonData.forEach((curr) => {

  // filter test
  if (/abc/i.test(curr.index)) {
    filtered.push(curr);

    // max value test
    const [digits] = curr.index.match(/\d+/);
    const test = parseInt(digits);
    if (test > max) {
      max = test;
      item = curr;
    }
  }
});

console.log('Item:\n', item, '\n\n----\nFiltered:\n', filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying - was in middle of posting my reply and yours got updated. Its similar to what I have done. Will compare both.

Answer (score 2):

Following is a crude and unsatisfactory implementation:

```
//filter out matching objects for possible future use
var latest = "";
var matches = _.filter(jsonData, function (o) { 
    var ret = /abc/i.test(o.index);
    if (ret) {            
        var digits = o.index.replace(/\D/g,'')            
        if (parseInt(digits) > latest) {
            latest = digits;
            latestIndex = o.index
            console.log(latest+">>>latestIndex")
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    });
    console.log("latestIndex->"+latest);
}
```

Comment: What if index is `213abc43`?

Comment: @Tushar - It won't in my case - but yes this is just a crude implementation and there are way better solutions mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it using lodash is by replacing `filter` with `maxBy` in your code.

Of course, this has the downside that if no valid elements exist in the collection, it'll arbitrarily return an invalid one. So, after getting the result, an extra validity check is needed.

This is why I have extracted the validation/filter code in a separate function:

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "index": "xyz",
}, {
  "index": "abc1234",
}, {
  "index": "xyz",
}, {
  "index": "abc5678",
}];

var isValid = function(o) {
  return /abc/i.test(o.index);
};

var highest = _.maxBy(jsonData, isValid);

if (isValid(highest)) {
  console.log('The max value is: ' + highest.index);
} else {
  console.log('No valid value found!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And here's how it works if there are no valid elements:

```js
var jsonDataWithoutValidValues = [{
  "index": "xyz",
}, {
  "index": "xyz",
}];

var isValid = function(o) {
  return /abc/i.test(o.index);
};

var highest = _.maxBy(jsonDataWithoutValidValues , isValid);

if (isValid(highest)) {
  console.log('The max value is: ' + highest.index);
} else {
  console.log('No valid value found!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This is a probably a bit weird to use in production, but I thought it was interesting enough to share.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case you can just use Array prototype sort after you have filtered out the 'abc' to sort them the way you want

```
var x = _.filter(jsonData, function (o) { 
      return /abc/i.test(o.index); 
  }).sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a.index > b.index) return -1;
    if(a.index < b.index) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
```

if you do the sorting correct you can get the highest value like

```
console.log(x[0].index)
```

Comment: Note that this code sorts the list, while only a max is needed. So it is O(n log n) instead of just O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single loop with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check the number, if exists.

```js
var data = [{ index: "xyz" }, { index: "abc1234" }, { index: "xyz" }, { index: "abc5678" }],
    getNumber = function (s) { return s.match(/^abc(\d+)/i)[1]; },
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a.index.match(/^abc\d/i) && (!r || getNumber(r.index) < getNumber(a.index)) ? a : r;
    }, undefined);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lodash chaining approach:

```
_(data)
  .map('index')
  .filter(_.method('match', /abc/))
  .maxBy(_.flow(_.bindKey(/\d+/, 'exec'), _.first, _.toNumber));
```

The `map()` and `filter()` calls get you a list of stings with `abc` in them. The `maxBy()` call finds the max, but we have to compose a function to tell it that we want to compare it numerically. The `flow()` function is really handy for this. Here, we're telling it to execute the regular expression, find the first element of the result, and turn that into a number.